# Aggrid-react editable wrap text

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to wrap the text in an editable comment field. It doesn't fit the height to match the content of the text after i hit enter nor does it fit to height when there was text before editing. I've tried several ways:

First way, set `getRowHeight` in `gridOptions`

```
gridOptions = {
...
getRowHeight: function (params) {
        if (params.node && params.node.detail) {
          if (params.data && params.data.comments.legnth > 10) {
            return params.data.comments.length * 50; // just testing this ridiculous length, doesnt work
          }
        } else return 50;
      },
}
```

second way, in my columnDef, define the `cellStyle`

```
{
          headerName: 'Comment',
          field: 'comment',
          width: 1050,
          editable: function(params) {
            return params.data.editable;
          },
          valueGetter: function(params) {
            return params.data ? params.data.comment : null;
          },
          valueSetter: function(params) {
            if (params.data.comment !== params.newValue) {
              params.data.comment = params.newValue;
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          },
          autoHeight: true,
          cellStyle: {
            'white-space': 'normal' //only way i can see the text is overflow, which isnt the desire intention
          }
        }
```

Third way, on `onGridReady` and where there's a change in data grouping:
`gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(['comments']);`